# ZK onKeyUp with regex

Tags: java, regex, zk, onkeyup

I am trying to make zk textbox behave like only numeric values . For this above code works great

```
<textbox id="telNo" xmlns:w="client" >
<attribute w:name="doKeyPress_">
  function(evt){
       if (!this._shallIgnore(evt, "0123456789"))
          this.$doKeyPress_(evt);
  }
</attribute>
```

But also I need to check that if first value starts whit 0 or 5 or .. to do this I am trying to make regular expression but no success. My regex **^5[0-9]{8}** How can I implement this regex chek to my function?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not the issue for regex,
you could take a look in InputWidget , where implements the shallIgnore.

https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/inp/InputWidget.js

```
_shallIgnore: function (evt, keys) {
    var code = (zk.ie||zk.opera) ? evt.keyCode : evt.charCode;
    if (!evt.altKey && !evt.ctrlKey && _keyIgnorable(code)
    && keys.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(code)) < 0) {
        evt.stop();
        return true;
    }
},
```

And you will find it's only detecting for one char.

Since it's not match the whole word, (it's bad performance and useless in general case)
so there's alternate for not using regex in your case.

```
<textbox id="telNo" xmlns:w="client" >
  <attribute w:name="doKeyPress_">
    function(evt){
         if(this.getValue().length > 0 ){
           if (!this._shallIgnore(evt, "0123456789"))
              this.$doKeyPress_(evt);
         }else{
           if (!this._shallIgnore(evt, "05"))
              this.$doKeyPress_(evt);
         }
    }
  </attribute>
</textbox>
```

You could test the code on the ZK Fiddle platform.

http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1b3nlr0/1-Textbox-input-restriction-sample

If you really want to use regex for input mask , 
it's not impossible , you could do the steps below.

1.Get the old value

2.Try to add the new char to the value  (Have to ignore the case for some special keycode as shallIgnore did)

3.use the full text do the regex , if not matching , stop the event and return false in the onKeyPress.

But in your use-case , I think the sample is good enough.

---

You could still have another choose , for using jquery mask plugin, ZK could works well with most jQuery plugin.

http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/